# unrecognized data type error in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

when i do this :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT id, name FROM users;
```

it works but when i try to change the columns names while doing so by typing this line

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (user_id, user_name) AS SELECT id, name FROM users;
```

this error shows

```
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized data type. (near "," at position 36)
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "user_name" at position 38)
```

i tried it with different tables but the same error occurs, looked it up and found that my code is correct so what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The `create table` statement requires column types.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (user_id int, user_name varchar(255)) AS
    SELECT id, name FROM users;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07a6141d3e7513b921c692c76ffe134a) is a db<>fiddle.

Or, alternatively, change the names in the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
    SELECT id as user_id, name as user_name
    FROM users;
```

Comment: but that creates a table with null columns plus the columns from users

Comment: @LrAyman: Try to combine the two, i.e. use the aliases in the first one too (`CREATE TABLE new_table (user_id int, user_name varchar(255)) AS
    SELECT id user_id, name user_name FROM users;`).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff the second one works but im still curious to why my code produced that error. [https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-table-as.html#change-column-names](you can find an example in this tutorial)

Comment: @LrAyman . . . Because you need to specify the types in `create table` if you specify the names.